# Problem with Html5 <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem with html5  element. I implemented a canvas and when i enter the site don't run, but when I refresh the page, runs correctly. Also only runs with Firefox. Why I have to refresh and why not in other browsers?

The site is: http://www.dendrosite.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are drawing images and not necessarily waiting for them to load.

When you refresh, the image is already loaded, so the problem goes away.

From the [Mozilla tutorial:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images)

> When this script gets executed, the
>   image starts loading. Trying to call
>   drawImage before the image has
>   finished loading will throw in gecko
>   1.9.2 and earlier, and silently do nothing in Gecko 2.0 and later.  So
>   you must use an onload event handler:

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.onload = function(){
  // execute drawImage statements here
};
img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path
```